# Refresh Main Window When Secondary Window Is Closed PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

In PyQt5, I have a window which reads from a database and adds that information to a widget. There is also a second window, which, when opened, adds a new table to the database. What I'm trying to do is reload the main window when the secondary window is closed. I don't want to change the secondary window to a `QDialoge` and need to use `.show()`, not `.exec_()`. Is there any way I could do this.

There is my code:

```py
import sys
import sqlite3
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QListWidget, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class SecondWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setWindowTitle("App 2")

        label = QLabel("INSERTED VALUES")

        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        
        self.setCentralWidget(label)

        #Open Database
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("connections.db")
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

        #Add New Table To Database
        self.cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE `New`
                     (name text, GD text)''')

        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setWindowTitle("App")
        
        self.list = QListWidget()

        self.cursorCount = 0

        #Open Database
        self.conn = sqlite3.connect("connections.db")
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

        try:
            #Try To Create A Table If It Doesn't exit
            self.cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE `Default`
                     (name text, GD text)''')
        except:
            pass

        #Get A List Of All The Tables
        self.cursor.execute('SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type= "table"')

        for table in self.cursor.fetchall():
            self.list.insertItem(self.cursorCount, table[0])
            self.cursorCount += 1

        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()

        self.list.item(0).setSelected(True)
        

        self.btn = QPushButton()
        self.btn.setText("click me!")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.openWin)

        winWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(winWidget)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.list)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        winWidget.setLayout(layout)

    def openWin(self):
        self.win = SecondWindow()
        self.win.show()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec_()
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why do you need to use `show()` and not `exec_()`?

Comment: The code above is the program in a nutshell, doing the basics. Once completed. the second window is actually going to contain many more features. Therefore, for later on, I need it to be `.show()`

Comment: Then create a custom signal in the secondary window, connect it from the main window and emit the signal whenever it's needed.

Comment: How would I do that. I've never used signals before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I got your problem right but I think you could use signals from PyQt5 and the closeEvent method. Basically, you should create a signal in the second window that will be emitted when the close event happens, and connect this signal to a slot in the first window.

import with:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
```

when declaring the second window class, before **init**, declare your signal:

```
class SecondWindow(QMainWindow):
    window_closed = pyqtSignal()
```

create a method named closeEvent that will be called when you close the window, and when it happens it should emit the signal you previously declared:

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    self.window_closed.emit()
    event.accept()
    # event.ignore() # if you want the window to never be closed
```

and modify the MainWindow openWin method to connect the signal from the second window to the method you want to be called:

```
def openWin(self):
    self.win = SecondWindow()
    self.win.window_closed.connect(self.do_something)
    self.win.show()

def do_something(self):
    print("You closed the second window!")
```

**Edit:**

The entire code should be something like this (I removed the parts database related to test myself, seems to be working fine).

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QListWidget, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSignal

class SecondWindow(QMainWindow):

    window_closed = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SecondWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle("App 2")
        label = QLabel("INSERTED VALUES")
        label.setAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setCentralWidget(label)

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.window_closed.emit()
        event.accept()
        # event.ignore() # if you want the window to never be closed

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle("App")
        self.btn = QPushButton()
        self.btn.setText("click me!")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.openWin)
        winWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(winWidget)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        winWidget.setLayout(layout)

    def openWin(self):
        self.win = SecondWindow()
        self.win.window_closed.connect(self.do_something)
        self.win.show()

    def do_something(self):
        print("You closed the second window!")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Could you perhaps post all the code because when I run it, I get an error saying that `SecondWindow has no attribute window_closed`

Comment: I've just edited the answer to include it. Also, i would suggest this playlist [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIg9ehmGJHY&list=PLXlKT56RD3kAingA-ByP0B2O97M_QVaLZ&index=4). It helped me a lot to understand the basics of PyQt5.